# Attribute Error: `loss.backward()` returns None

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent, fast-ai

I'm trying to implement the `Learner` object and its steps and facing an issue with the `loss.backward()` function as it raises and `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'`

The entire process works when I follow the **Chapter 04 MNIST Basics**. However, implementing within a class raises this error. Could anybody guide me on why this occurs and ways to fix this?

Here's the code below:

```
class Basic_Optim:
    
    def __init__(self, params, lr):
        self.params = list(params)
        self.lr = lr
        
    def step(self):
        for p in self.params:
            p.data -= self.lr * p.grad.data
    
    def zero(self):
        for p in self.params:
            p.grad = None


class Learner_self:
    
    def __init__(self, train, valid, model, loss, metric, params, lr):
        self.x = train
        self.y = valid
        self.model = model
        self.loss = loss
        self.metric = metric
        self.opt_func = Basic_Optim(params, lr)   
        
    def fit(self, epochs):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.train_data()
            score = self.valid_data()
            print(score, end = ' | ')
            
    def train_data(self):
        for x, y in self.x:
            preds = self.model(x)
            loss = self.loss(preds, y)
            loss_b = loss.backward()
            print(f'Loss: {loss:.4f}, Loss Backward: {loss_b}')
            
            self.opt_func.step()
            self.opt_func.zero()
    
    def valid_data(self):
        accuracy = [self.metric(xb, yb) for xb, yb in self.y]
        return round(torch.stack(accuracy).mean().item(), 4)
    
    
learn = Learner_self(dl, valid_dl, simple_net, mnist_loss, metric=batch_accuracy,
                     params=linear_model.parameters(), lr = 1)
learn.fit(10)
```

**OUTPUT** from the print statement inside the `train_data` prints: `Loss: 0.0516, Loss Backward: None` and then raises the Attribute error shared above.

***Please let me know if you want any more details.*** Every other function such as `mnist_loss`, `batch_accuracy`, `simple_net` are exactly the same from the [book](https://github.com/snehangsude/fastbook/blob/master/04_mnist_basics.ipynb).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree with Shai's answer, just wanted to add that `Tensor.backward()` isn't supposed to return anything, so getting `None` is expected behavior.

Comment: A follow-up question to this: 

How does the `.grad` value have the updated value based on the `loss.backward()` call, since `None` is the expected behavior. Thank you!

Comment: `None` is the expected *return* value. There are, however, *side effects* from calling `.backward()`. Most notably the `.grad` attribute for all the leaf tensors that `loss` is calculated from are updated. This is accomplished by following the computation graph that loss is a part of via the `loss.grad_fn` attribute. You can read more about the autograd mechanic on the pytorch website. This tutorial is pretty good IMO: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your optimizer and your trainer do not work on the same model.
You have `model=simple_net`, while the parameters for the optimizer are those of a *different* model `params=linear_model.parameters()`.

Try passing `params=simple_net.parameters()` -- that is, make sure the trainer's `params` are those of `model`.

Comment: Thank you! Damn! I feel so stupid now! Was able to run and fix it!
I had a misunderstanding on that Chapter got that cleared as well. Much thanks! :D